# How to stop gridview column from automatically encoding html entities

Tags: asp.net, html-encode

I am fairly new to asp.net and come into a problem whilst using a gridview.

I have added some entries that contain the "&" symbol eg "PR Murphy & Associates".
I haven't done any encoding of my data prior to inserting it into the database.

When the gridview is changed to edit mode my text looks like this: "PR Murphy & Associates"

Is thee a ny way I can stop it from encoding the information, I mean just keep the text as "PR Murphy & Associates" when inserting and then after/during an edit.

Thanking you

Comment: I am quite convinced that the GridView control does the right thing. Maybe your expectations are wrong? In what situation would encoding the HTML entities be undesired?

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm inclined to agree with you. The only time I ever have to turn off HTMLEncoding is when I am trying to do string formatting on columns that contain information such as currency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the GridView's menu, you can select the column and under the properties for that column you can set HTMLEncode to False (or True depending upon your needs).

Comment: The field is not a bound field though. It is a <asp:TextBox> inside a template field.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with `GridView1_RowDataBound` Event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
           for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++) 
           {
               string encoded = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
               e.Row.Cells[i].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded);
           }
    }
}
```